# Python Numba Value in Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I am trying to check if a number is in NumPy array of `int8`s. I tried this, but it does not work.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def c(b):
    return 9 in b

a = np.array((9, 10, 11), 'int8')
print(c(a))
```

The error I get is

```
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function contains>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(int8, 1d, C), Literal[int](9))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at .\emptyList.py (6)
```

How can I fix this while still maintaining performance?
The arrays will be checked for two values, 1 and -1, and are 32 items long. They are not sorted.

Comment: It looks like in is not supported by Numba for numpy-arrays, but it is supported for sets. So the only thing you have to do is to change b to set(b)

Comment: @max9111 If I understand correctly, won't that take a while? I will be doing this many times so speed is important.

Comment: The fastest algortithm depends on the data.  (Are the arrays sorted? Do you want to check for more than one value if it is in the array?)

Comment: @max9111 The arrays are not sorted, and I am checking for two values, 1 and -1. The array will be 32 items long. I will add this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Checking if two values are in an array

For checking only if two values occur in an array I would recommend a simple brute force algorithm.

**Code**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def isin(b):
  for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    res=False
    if (b[i]==-1):
      res=True
    if (b[i]==1):
      res=True
  return res

#Parallelized call to isin if the data is an array of shape (n,m)
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def isin_arr(b):
  res=np.empty(b.shape[0],dtype=nb.boolean)
  for i in nb.prange(b.shape[0]):
    res[i]=isin(b[i,:])

  return res
```

**Performance**

```
#Create some data (320MB)
A=(np.random.randn(10000000,32)-0.5)*5
A=A.astype(np.int8)
res=isin_arr(A) 11ms per call
```

So with this method I get a throughput of about 29GB/s which isn't far away from memory bandwith. You can also try to reduce the Testdatasize so that it will fit in L3-cache to avoid the memory-bandwith limit. With 3.2 MB Testdata I get a throuput of 100 GB/s (far beyond my the memory bandwith), which is a clear indicator that this implementation is memory bandwidth limited.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the code could reach the speeds it does.

Comment: Having `res=False` inside the for loop seems unintended.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slight variation on the answer by max9111. A little shorter, and takes the element to search for as an argment. It also exits the loop once the element is found.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def isin(val, arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == val:
            return True
    return False
```