# efficient way to check if value not in array with Python Numba

Tags: python, python-3.7, numba

I am trying to find an efficient way to make the following statement:

```
if value not in array:
```

work with Python Numba (where value is an integer and array an array of integers). This statement does not seem to be compatible with Numba (version 0.50.1).

Is there an efficient way to write this for Numba ?

Comment: Do you want to check for multiple values? -> create a set and check if the values are in the set. For one or only a few values simply loop over the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@numba.njit` function to help you.

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930852/python-numba-value-in-array) with sample code to help you implement it in your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link shows you how to check if an item IS in the array, so you will have to use an 'if/else' statement to check if the item IS NOT in the array.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gavin, I tried to go with a brute force approach but I used `np.where()`:

```
@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def belongs(val,vec):
    res = False
    if np.where(vec == val)[0].shape[0] > 0:
        res = True
    return res
```

Though I would be surprised this is the most efficient way to go...